# How to have a decorator access variables from the decorated function?

Tags: python, timeout, signals, decorator, python-decorators

I'm using a generic Python timeout decorater. I want the decorater to access variables from the function it is decorating. In this example, I want message to pass from the prepare function into the timeout function. I don't want to use a global variable as that sounds like bad practice.

```
def timeout(seconds):
    def decorator(func):
        def _handle_timeout(signum, frame):
            # Do something with variable message
            print("Sending the message didn't work!")
            print(message)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_timeout)
            signal.alarm(seconds)
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                signal.alarm(0)
            return result

        return wraps(func)(wrapper)

    return decorator

@timeout(5)
def prepare(message):
    """Deploy app using Heroku to the MTurk Sandbox."""
    print("Preparing to send message!")
    send(message)
```

Comment: It already does have access to the parameters, what do you think is in `args`?

Comment: I'm receiving an error that the variable does not exist.. I can't seem to pass the variable into the _handle_timeout function.

Comment: Well that function is *outside* `wrapper`, so it doesn't have access to those arguments. Note that you should give a [mcve] that includes the specific error traceback.

Comment: Got it, i'll edit my example. So I assume I need to fix the _handle_timeout so that it can accept the variable in wrapper? I'll test this out and provide more details.

Comment: Vishal: In the `wrapper()` method, `args[0]` will be the `message` argument being passed in the `prepare(message)` call.

Comment: jonrsharpe, martineau: The problem really isn't whether or not the wrapper can get to the message (though in my answer below I made it plain to see) it's that the signal.signal method doesn't accept arbitrary arguments.

Comment: @Andrew: I understand the problem and saying that it's the fact that the handler function passed to `signal.signal()` won't accept additional arguments is somewhat misleading. It's that it needs to somehow access one of the arguments that was passed to the decorated function without requiring them to be passed to it as one or more arguments—so it needs to do that using some other technique.

Comment: @martineau this approach (nesting functions in order to gain scope) is completely acceptable in Python. Also, it works.

Comment: @Andrew: I never said your answer wasn't any good (in fact I up-voted it)—only that your comment here under the question is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push the handler into the wrapper so that it has access to that variable.

```
from functools import wraps
import signal
import time

def timeout(seconds):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(message, *args, **kwargs):
            def _handle_timeout(signum, frame):
                # Do something with variable message
                print("Sending the message didn't work!")
                print(message)
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_timeout)
            signal.alarm(seconds)
            try:
                result = func(message, *args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                signal.alarm(0)
            return result

        return wraps(func)(wrapper)

    return decorator

@timeout(1)
def prepare(message):
    # Uncomment to force error
    # time.sleep(3)
    """Deploy app using Heroku to the MTurk Sandbox."""
    print("Preparing to send message!")
    print(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    prepare("hi")
```